# Can't get my web-service to work with tomcat & axis2

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

Firstly, english is not my native language so if there are some mistakes you can edit my post.

**Question:** I have created a simple code, what I want is running it on my server. So I will know what a web server will look like.

```
public class OperatorClass {

    public int sum(int a , int b) {
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

I have created all the folders/classes/packages required.

Here is a screenshot so you can see:

https://i.gyazo.com/2971a09e9bca2e8e5f221fbfc72c2ab8.png

But when I click run this code on server, it says `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`

I already switched the location of server, and also clicked the "use tomcat installation" radio button on properties. But nothing changed.

One solution I find is right clicking on the project and then say "run-on server"

When I do this, instead of 404-Not Found error, I'm getting this screen:

https://i.gyazo.com/bf2230e2a3dd395701a430dc971cdea7.png

But after clicking one of the links in the image, I got another error. For example when I click "Services" I got this:

> > HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Servlet.init() for servlet [AxisServlet] threw exception
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   [AxisServlet] threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
>   Source)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Root Cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>     org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
>   Source)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Root Cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>     org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
>   Source)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.

How can I fix this guys? I'm really beginner with this stuff but I followed the tutorials on youtube but I can't make this work.

Comment: Could you share the url through which you are trying to access the webservice and getting 404 error? Also, It would be helpful if you can give reference of the youtube tutorial you are following.

Comment: @YugSingh in Eclipse, when I run the code, it automatically direct me to "http://localhost:8081/AddServiceServer/" When it was 8080 I was getting another error so I changed it to 8081. Btw you can see this in one of my screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

As on your error, clearly said class not found exception. this would be helpful, [Reference_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188087/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-ws-commons-schema-resolver-uriresolve) and [Tutorial_Reference](https://www.journaldev.com/255/axis2-web-services-tutorial). If you provide some more code which you used it might be helpful. Cheers.

Comment: There is no other codes...just this. Like I said I just want to see how a web service works.